# Using up arrow to run previous command

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys, 8.04

What setup do I need to use up-arrow to run previous command?
With Mac, I can use up-arrow to rerun the command that I just run, but it doesn't seem to work with my bash shell.

I use 8.04 (I can't use the newest distribution because of some compiler version issues).

### ADDED

I didn't change anything as it's a fresh install with VMWare Fusion on Mac.

Comment: In the default configuration, up arrow works perfectly: have you modified somethings?

Comment: as @enzotib says bash will do this by default, but some others, eg sh will not!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure that your history is enabled. You can check the current status by running:

```
set -o
```

The output should contain (note the `history on` line):

```
histexpand      on
history         on
ignoreeof       off
```

If this is not enabled, you need to run `set -o history`. To make this change persistent, you need to append it to `~/.bashrc`:

```
set -o history
```

---

If you want to run the previous command, you can run the next command as well:

```
!!
```

From [Bash manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man1/bash.1.html):

```
Event Designators
   An event designator is a reference to a command line entry in the history list.

   !      Start a history substitution, except when followed by a blank, newline,
          carriage return, = or ( (when the extglob shell option  is
          enabled using the shopt builtin).
   !n     Refer to command line n.
   !-n    Refer to the current command line minus n.
   !!     Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym for `!-1'.
   !string
          Refer to the most recent command starting with string.
   !?string[?]
          Refer to the most recent command containing string.  The trailing ? 
          may be omitted if string is followed immediately by a newline.
   ^string1^string2^
          Quick  substitution.  Repeat the last command, replacing string1 with
          string2.  Equivalent to ``!!:s/string1/string2/'' (see Modifiers below).
   !#     The entire command line typed so far.
```

If you're using Bash, you can use the default shortcuts for navigating through the history as well:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>: Previous command
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>: Next command

  Commands for Manipulating the History
     previous-history (C-p)
            Fetch the previous command from the history list, moving back in
            the list.
     next-history (C-n)
            Fetch  the next command from the history list, moving forward in
            the list.

Comment: I checked the setup is correct, but the up-arrow key doesn't work. However, I can use Ctrl-P/N for getting the same result. Thanks.

Comment: @prosseek In that case, have you changed `/etc/inputrc` or `~/.inputrc`? Also, what escape sequence does the up and down arrow produce in the terminal you're using? To check, run `cat`, then on the empty line, hit uparrow and downarrow, then Ctrl+C to exit cat. Here it produces `^[[A^[[B`.

Comment: @geirha : I don't have the ~/.inputrc file, and I didn't change anything /etc/inputrc. And for the escape sequence, I got nothing seen in the screen.

Comment: @prosseek Then it sounds like the arrow keys never reach the terminal at all. Perhaps the VMWare interface is filtering them out or something.

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you are actually using bash. A common gotcha is creating a new user with `useradd` instead of `adduser` or the Users and groups (GUI) application. With the former, the default shell set is `/bin/sh`. Run
`chsh` (**ch**ange **sh**ell) to make sure it's set to `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 2):

In terminal enter:

```
gedit  ~/.inputrc
```

Then copy paste and save:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[C": forward-char
"\e[D": backward-char
```

From now on in terminal you can do incremental search, All you need to do to find a previous command is to enter say the first two or three letters and upward arrow will take you there quickly.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

- Edit /etc/inputrc like `vi /etc/inputrc`
- Uncomment the following lines

```
#"\e[5~": history-search-backward
#"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

- And change them to

```
# Arrow Up
"\e[A": history-search-backward
# Arrow Down
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

Answer (score 0):

Had env var HISTSIZE defined with value -1.

```
unset HISTSIZE
```

fixed it