# Install history command package

Tags: command-line, history

I have **Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS** running on a proxmox OpenVZ container.

I imagine it does not come with history because the up arrow on the command line gives me `^[[A`

plus...

```
$ history
-sh: history: not found
```

But I get this when I trying to install.

```
$ sudo apt-get install history
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package history
```

**What is the correct package name I need to install to get history working?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `history` command is a feature of **bash**. For some reason, Your system might be running **dash** instead of bash. Perhaps, you need to change your login shell to /bin/bash (should have been the default). Type the below command in terminal:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Then, log out and log in.

If you did not install **bash** in your system, you can install it by the command:

```
sudo apt-get install bash
```

Although, you can use other shell like **zsh** or **tcsh** (including history).

Comment: This worked, although I don't know why. Because I had no history with my user but when I changed to `root` I had. So could it be two users use different shells?

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is `bash` own history, which is typically saved in `~/.bash_history` file, and this functionality is embedded into `bash` itself. No need to install additional packages.

Please have a look at this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34536/using-up-arrow-to-run-previous-command) on how to check and enable `bash` history.

Also, there is a chance that you are not using `bash`, but some other shell. Use `chsh` command to change your shell.

Comment: Thanks it was chsh... had to give it to vine_user for giving me the command line. (+1).